# Remapping Ctrl-l in vim works in my personal setup, but not my work setup. How do I make it work in my work environment?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

In my personal configuration files I have the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohlsearch<CR><C-l>
```

See the actual content [here](https://github.com/harleypig/dotvim/blob/459801e31fc91320b767c0d088669307c9acc5b1/.vim/bundle/my-stuff/after/plugin/set.vim#L59).

This setup works fine in my personal setup, but not my work environment. My personal systems have version 8.0+, but my work systems have 7.4. I can't show my work environment, but it's a file copy with all the cruft and unusable mappings removed. Other mappings are working fine.

I got this idea from a previous StackOverflow question, and it's been a minimum of 6 years, so I don't think it's a version issue. But I can't think of what else it might be.

How can I track this down and fix it?

Comment: what does `:map <c-l>` output?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. ':map <c-l>' shows a different mapping. Digging through the configuration files I found a co-worker's mapping to <c-l> in a file that is processed later. It never even occurred to me to check for that because most of my co-workers use vi and don't use any of the "fancy" stuff. Changing the mapping to <c-m> works. Now I just need to train my muscles.

Comment: I guess this mapping is not in your co-workers personal configuration file, but in some sort of a plugin? you could overwrite it in your `vimrc` with an `autocmd` or in the after directory (see `:h after`)

Comment: Unfortunately, my work environment uses a shared account for development purposes. I'm not aware of a way to setup different configuration files for the same user that doesn't involve painful contortions.

Comment: well you could start vim with your own `vimrc` with the `-u` parameter: `vim -u myowncoolvimrcwithoutdumbmappingsfrommycoworker`. Also of course then you just have to define an alias for that command so you could use `harleyvimson` or something like that for your own configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When having this kind of trouble, the first thing you should do is check the output of ':map '.

In this case there was a later mapping. Remapping my setup made things work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

My issue had a different source but the end effect was the same. I could not navigate between tabs of my vim when I had list of files open in a tab, I have mapping ctrl+h to move left tab and ctrl+l to move right tab, it was because on default when opening file browser ctrl+l was remapped to `n <C-L> @<Plug>NetrwRefresh`.

After I figured out what's the issue I found this:

https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator/issues/189

After modyfing vimrc to look like this:

```
nmap <C-h> :tabprev<CR>
nmap <C-l> :tabnext<CR>
nmap cw :tabnew<CR>

augroup netrw_mapping
  autocmd!
  autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
augroup END

function! NetrwMapping()
  nnoremap <buffer> <C-l> :tabnext<CR>
endfunction
```

It was fixed.